# command substitution does not respect err_exit sometimes

Tags: zsh, command-substitution, error-handling

I have a weird situation where inserting any command that succeeds in the line above makes command substitution (`$(I mean this)`) not work as expected — it does not exit, even though the command fails and err_exit is set.

I keep thinking it must be something to do with subshells behaving differently from what I think they should, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

This prints “should have exited above”:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
setopt local_options err_exit warn_create_global nounset

local x
if false; then
else
    x=$(false)
    echo 'should have exited above'
fi
```

This prints nothing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
setopt local_options err_exit warn_create_global nounset

local x
if false; then
else
    true
    x=$(false)
    echo 'should have exited above'
fi
```

Obviously I can make my script work correctly by leaving that `true` in, but it doesn't seem correct and I can't even explain it. So what is happening, and what is the recommended solution?

Comment: Works as expected on zsh 5.1.1, behaves the way you describe with zsh 5.4.2. It's a bug in recent versions of zsh. Check if it's been reported.

Comment: I can reproduce this on 5.2.

Comment: git bisect says [b581c3fece76c87ed86ae9fc704d0fcf208a79d3](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/b581c3fece76c87ed86ae9fc704d0fcf208a79d3/) is the first bad commit (so 5.1.1 is the last non-buggy version). I guess that this change is incompatible with some optimization done elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug. Here's a smaller test case.

```
set -e; if false; then :; else x=$(false); echo "$? $-"; fi
```

The assignment `x=$(false)` should have the status of the last command substitution in it, which is 1. Without `set -e`, this snippet should print `1` followed by the active shell options. With `set -e`, this snippet should exit before it prints anything.

Zsh 5.1.1 works correctly (exit with status 1). Dash, bash, mksh, ksh93 all have the same behavior.

Zsh checked out from Git today prints `1 569Xe` and exits with status 0. If you add a call to `false` before `echo`, the script exits as expected. It looks like `errexit` has no effect on `x=$(false)` even though it should. `git bisect` says [b581c3fece76c87ed86ae9fc704d0fcf208a79d3](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/b581c3fece76c87ed86ae9fc704d0fcf208a79d3/) is the first bad commit.

It's now been [reported on the zsh workers mailing list](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2020/msg00196.html) and [fixed a few hours later](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2020/msg00198.html) in [that commit](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/e01223a26cb7afd9f44805f067c4dcdad06039b0/) which will be included in the next release.